# emacs can't overwrite user's own write protection on file

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, emacs

On a recently installed fedora 25 system (`uname -a` → `Linux [host] 4.10.6-200.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 27 14:06:23 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`; using `GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.4) of 2016-12-15` according to emacs' own opening page), I am unable to overwrite in emacs the write protection of my own files.

This is the way it happens:

(a) I open my write-protected file (`ls -l` → `-r--------. 1 me me 92996 Apr 10 20:44 myfile`),

(b) I disable write protection so I can edit (<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd>)

(c) I edit the file

(d) I want to save (<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd>)

(e) I am prompted "File `myfile` is write-protected; try to save anyway? (yes or no) "

(f) I answer "yes", enter

(g) The message appears: "Opening output file: Permission denied, [full path]/myfile"

The directory is not write protected.

I have been able to edit and save my write-protected files forever on other systems (opensuse in the most recent years).

Disabling selinux mode on the system doesn't help.  Please see more information in the comments.

I am unable to figure out what may be wrong.

Comment: What about SELinux labels? Are there any AVCs?

Comment: How can I check those?  I am not sure what they are.  However, note that the problem persists even when I disable selinux (after I set SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config and reboot afterwards).

Comment: In my home directory (selinux disabled, see my previous comment)  "ls -lZ" on the write protected "myfile" gives: [code] r--r--r-- 1 iam iam ? 12 Apr 12 13:14 ./myfile[code/].  On my home directory, the "ls -lZd ." command gives [code]drwxr-xr-x. 52 iam iam system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 4096 Apr 12 13:15 ./[code/]

Comment: In my home directory (selinux disabled, see my previous comment)  "ls -lZ" on the write protected "myfile" gives: `r--r--r-- 1 iam iam ? 12 Apr 12 13:14 ./myfile`.  On my home directory, the "ls -lZd ." command gives `drwxr-xr-x. 52 iam iam system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 4096 Apr 12 13:15 ./` The `ausearch -m avc` command seems to give no relevant information.  Is this what you asked for?

Comment: Yes. It was that. But in case it does the same with disabled SELinux, it will not be the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Is there anything else I may try?

Answer (score 1):

`C-x C-q` disables read-only for the **buffer**, not for its file.

The purpose of `C-x C-q` is to prevent yourself from accidentally changing the content of a buffer (whether or not it is a file buffer).

**To change the permissions of a *file***, use one of the following:

- Command `chmod`
- Dired, with `M` (command `dired-do-chmod`)

Use `C-h f` to see the doc of each command:

---

> **`chmod`** is an alias for `set-file-modes` in `subr.el`.
>
> `(chmod FILENAME MODE)`
>
> Set mode bits of file named `FILENAME` to `MODE` (an integer).
>   Only the 12 low bits of `MODE` are used.
>
> Interactively, mode bits are read by `read-file-modes`, which accepts
>   symbolic notation, like the `chmod` command from GNU Coreutils.

---

> **`dired-do-chmod`** is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   `dired-aux.el`.
>
> It is bound to **`M`**, `<menu-bar> <operate> <chmod>`.
>
> `(dired-do-chmod &optional ARG)`
>
> Change the mode of the marked (or next `ARG`) files.
>   Symbolic modes like `g+w` are allowed.
>   Type `M-n` to pull the file attributes of the file at point
>   into the minibuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your attention.
The question turned mute yesterday because, having given up on the problem, I ended up installing another linux distribution where emacs (there, emacs v24) behaves as usual.

Although my original problem hasn't been solved, I remain to entertain the following suspects for its cause:

Suspect 1: emacs 25, the version I had the problem with, may behave different from its predecessor in this respect.  A hint to different behavior in general is that, for example, it doesn't accept the version 24's configuration file .emacs

Suspect 2: some file system or distribution specific setting.

Neither of the two suspicions have been followed up on, confirmed, or refuted.

Response to the previous answer (on chmod etc.): thank you for your input, but I am afraid you misunderstood my question (perhaps I was not clear enough to begin with).  My problem was not how emacs can change a file's permissions, but: why in my case it refused to overwrite a protected file even when the user requested such action?  (Indeed, C-x C-q changes only a buffer's editability, an editability that defaults after the permissions and/or kind of the file opened -- it was my mistake to use the wrong term for the effects of this keystroke combination.)

Comment: "*it refused to overwrite a protected file even when the user requested such action*". No. You did not request such action. That's not what `C-x C-q` does, as I explained. To "request such action" you need to use the **Emacs `chmod`** command. It's not about sending you to the OS `chmod` command. It's about the *Emacs* `chmod` command. That's what you use to "request such action" from Emacs.

Comment: You misunderstood me.  I "requested such action" in bullet (f) of my original post, in response to the prompt according to bullet (e).  In bullet (b), C-x C-q, I simply enabled buffer editing which had been disabled by default when emacs opened the write-protected file.  As I described, all other emacs-es / systems I used before did effectively accept a "yes" response to said prompt in bullet (e), I didn't have to invoke emacs' chmod or any other functions, just reply "yes" in bullet (f), and the write protection was overwritten for that particular save operation.

Comment: I see. Yes, Emacs tries to DTRT in that case. But the OS/file-manager might not let it. The code is in function `basic-save-buffer-2` of `files.el`, if you want to follow it in the debugger (`M-x debug-on-entry basic-save-buffer-2`) to see why it cannot save the file. But if you've already changed your Linux version and you no longer see the problem then you probably can't do that. ;-)